# Caught up in a Type Error: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django, django-views

I am following this particular tutorial ([tutorial link](https://medium.com/@adandan01/django-inline-formsets-example-mybook-420cc4b6225d)) to get my dynamic formsets working. I encountered this error which I am not sure where is it originated from or how to resolve it. Can someone tell me what could be done to resolve it? Yes, I know that this is a repetitive question here in SO. I have gone through many of those answers, but could not figure it out in my case.

View code:

```
    class ProfileList(ListView):
    model = Profile

class ProfileFamilyMemberCreate(CreateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('purchase_order')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ProfileFamilyMemberCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['familymembers'] = FamilyMemberFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['familymembers'] = FamilyMemberFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        familymembers = context['familymembers']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if familymembers.is_valid():
                familymembers.instance = self.object
                familymembers.save()
        return super(ProfileFamilyMemberCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Forms.py

```
class FamilyMemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FamilyMember
        exclude = ()

FamilyMemberFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Profile, FamilyMember,
                                            form=FamilyMemberForm, extra=1)
```

Traceback:

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/thahaabdulwahid/miniconda3/envs/projectEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/thahaabdulwahid/miniconda3/envs/projectEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/thahaabdulwahid/miniconda3/envs/projectEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /documents/purchase_order/
Exception Value: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Show the full traceback. And also the definition of FamileMemberFormSet, assuming that's the class causing the issue.

Comment: @DanielRoseman added details. Please have a look.

Comment: How are you referring to those views in the urls.py?

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^purchase_order/$',views.ProfileList, name='purchase_order')
]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem doesn't have anything to do with formsets, but is in the url configuration. For a class-based view, you need to call its `as_view()` method in the pattern:

```
 url(r'^purchase_order/$', views.ProfileList.as_view(), name='purchase_order')
```

See the [documentation for class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/#subclassing-generic-views).